# Deserializing relationships JSON API ActiveModelSerializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm using ActiveModelSerializers 0.10.2. - When I Deserializer my params, I'm unable to get my relationships to show up. I have a POST request with the payload:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "project_toolbox_talks",
    "attributes": {
      "date": "2017-12-11"
    }
  },
  "relationships": {
    "attendees": {
      "data": [
        {
          "type": "atendees",
          "id": "559ff2c9-beb6-47cd-9757-66104617403b"
        }
      ]
    },
    "projects": {
      "data": {
        "type": "projects",
        "id": "d9b28ffd-6f30-4dd0-a227-720caa9b881e"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Serializer for ProjectToolboxTalks is:

```
module API
  module V1
    class ProjectToolboxTalkSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :date

      has_one :toolbox_talk
      has_one :superintendent
      has_one :project
      has_many :attendees
      has_many :project_toolbox_talk_users
    end
  end
end
```

In my controller when I call:

```
ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(
  params, only: [:date, :attendees, :projects]
)
```

the only thing that is returned is `{:date=>"2017-12-11"}`

Why are my `attendees` or `projects` relationships not being returned?

ActiveModelSerializers 0.10.2 + Rails 5.1.2 + Ruby 2.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key 'relationships' needs to be inside the first 'data'.

Comment: smh. Will test once I'm back at my work computer...thank you.